# C++ map insert with custom key fails

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert

I have a custom class as a key in a map. When I try to insert an item into the map, the program terminates. There has to be a problem with the creation of the key.

```
class MyKey {
    char* data;
    bool operator<(const MyKey& s) const {
        for(int i = 0; i < (int)(sizeof(data)/sizeof(char)); i++) {
            if(data[i] > s.data[i])
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

map<MyKey, char>* map = new map<MyKey, char>;
MyKey* key = new MyKey(...);
map->insert(make_pair(*key, '0'));
```

The program terminates at the insert.

Comment: Could you post the implementation of `MyKey::operator<()` and definition of `MyKey` (need to see member variables and the copy constructor and assignment operator).

Comment: i added some information to the key class

Comment: Do you have a copy constructor in MyKey? What is the implementation?

Comment: is a copy constructor needed?

Comment: In your example code here, `data` never points to anything (and may not be initialized). Please show your FULL code for what you do with `data`.

Comment: where is data inilialized? you'll get a segfault if it does not point to valid memory. Apart from that, why not use an std::string? Another tip: just write for( size_t i = 0 ; ... instead of using an int and then performing a cast

Comment: Yes, as you have `char*` member variable so the default copy constructor is not enough (assuming this is allocated in constructor).

Comment: adding a copy constructor did the job

Comment: Apart from other listed errors, it seems that your less-than operator really performs a less-or-equal comparison. I don't think this is acceptable for establishing an ordering, where `a<b` and `b<a` can't be both true at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't determine the size of an array from the pointer alone like you're attempting to-do in the for-loop of your `operator<` function ... You will have to, at some point, pass in the size of the array that is being pointed to by `data` so that you don't overflow the bounds of the array `data` is pointing to.  Since `data` is a pointer, `sizeof(data)` simply returns the size of a pointer on your platform, not the size of the array being pointed to by `data`.

For C++, rather than using an allocated array, you should possibily use a STL container that you can directly query for the size of the container object ... this could include `std::string` if it's string-data, or `std::vector<unsigned char>` if it's just a bunch of binary bytes.

Answer (score 0):

From your example code, the operator < would not be called because you only insert one element in the map. And you said you don't implement a copy constructor. So following code would be a problem:

```
class MyKey {
public:
    MyKey()
    {
        data = new char[10];
    }
    ~MyKey()
    {
        delete data;
    }

private:
    char* data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works and prints A.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    using namespace std;

    class Key
    {
    public:
         Key(int x):data(x) {}
         bool operator<(const Key &k) const { return(data < k.data); }
    private:
         int data;
    };

   int main()
   {
        Key myKey(10);
        map<Key, char> m;
        m.insert(make_pair(myKey, 'A'));
        map<Key, char>::iterator it = m.find(myKey);
        if (it != m.end())
        {
            cout << (*it).second << endl;
        }
   }
```